# Dynamically update text from radio button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to get the text within the input tags to display the status of the radio button. The code works fine except for the very first time (the onload event). When the page loads the first alert is displayed but not the second. Once I click on the other radio button (the unchecked one) and then back to the original one, I see both alerts. Can someone please help me with why this is happening? I am sure it is something stupid. Thanks

```
<script>
window.onload = autoSelect("rolls");

function autoSelect(theValue)
    { 
        if(theValue=="rolls")
        {
            alert("hello world");
            document.getElementById("theLabel").innerHTML=theValue;
            alert("hello World");
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("theLabel").innerHTML=theValue;
        }
    }

</script>
<div >
<form action="" >
    <input type="radio" id="matRadioRolls" name="rollsOrSqFeet" value="rolls" onclick="autoSelect(this.value)" checked>Rolls<br/>
    <input type="radio" id="matRadioSqFt" name="rollsOrSqFeet" value="sqfeet" onclick="autoSelect(this.value)" >Sq Ft<br/>
</form>

<label class="productsLabel" for=rolls" id="theLabel"></label>
<input type="text" name="rolls" id="rollsMat"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be the type: `<label class="productsLabel" for="rolls" id="theLabel"></label>`. Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/xXLAd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually executing your function call before the window object has fully loaded. You should change the call to this:

```
window.onload = function(){autoSelect("rolls");}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DZwhL/)**

Oh, and a small side note. You have a typo in `for=rolls"` (missing a set of quotes).

Comment: Yep I sure do. Didn't notice that. Thanks very much and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here: Depends on what browser you are using. there is a chance that the browser supresses the second `alert` (because you clicked don't show again)

Generally: Use `console.log` over alert. Use the Dev Tools.